# get hardware scancode corresponding to XKeyPressedEvent

Tags: linux, x11, xinput

I am working on an open source project to add something in that i need. It uses an XInput system to get input from the keyboard and i cannot change that. However, for keypresses, i need to get the hardware scancodes, like those listed [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L75). Is there a way to go from an `XKeyPressedEvent` to these `KEY_*` scan codes from `input-event-codes.h`, to know what key was pressed in a layout independent way?

Comment: These are not hardware scancodes. Anyway the keycode member of the XKeyPressedEvent is layout-independent.

Comment: They are? So a table like [this](https://github.com/ingemaradahl/remote-input/blob/master/keysym_to_linux_code.c), for as far as the mapping isn't just completely obvious, would do the trick? Perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no idea what kind of a trick you are trying to pull and what keysyms have to do with it. I'm talking about keycodes, not keysyms. It's keycodes which are most closely resemble hardware scancodes, and it's keycodes that are layout independent. Keysyms are neither.

Comment: Ah, ok! Due to unfamiliarity with X11, i see now that googling let me astray. I though the ``XK_*`` is what you get in the keycode field. Good to know this is not what is in that field. [This](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/keyboard-encoding.html) would have told me.  Thanks, i got the info i need now. If you make your first comment an answer I'll select it. Thanks!

Comment: And for posteriority: [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys) seems very useful, and perhaps also [this](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkeycodes.html).